# Google cast ApiClient.connect failed return ConnectionResult{statusCode=Service_INVALID,resolution=null}

Tags: google-play-services, google-cast, chromecast

In my google cast app of android. When execute to mApiClient.connect(); return failed as following information:   ConnectionResult{statusCode=Service_INVALID,resolution=null}.

I have installed google play service v 4-2-43.apk. Why this still happens? Thanks!

Comment: There is very little info in your post to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I rooted my cellphone and reinstall the google play service again. It works.
This may because of rejection of Google play in China that most cellphones didn't have that.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution myself by root my cellphone and reinstall the Google Play Service again.